# Allowing anyone to View a webpage in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website designed using ASP.NET MVC4 which has a specific Controller 'ProductionLogs' which will display the top 25 logs from the Production Server on typing the URL https://(myapp.com)/ProductionLogs/GetTop25Logs . This is possible only for a user authorized to login to the application.,i.e, once they have correctly entered the UserName and Password and gained access into the application. But I have decided to make this URL available for anyone, without even be able to logging in. Just anyone who types the URL mentioned above, would be able to see the page displaying the latest 25 logs. How to go about?

[Note : I have eliminated the option of 'enabling the directory browsing' in the IIS Server. I have also eliminated the option of developing a custom HTTP module.]

Comment: You might want to explain how you have authorization configured currently. Globally? Attribute based?

Comment: You can decorate your controller method with the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute. This will allow that specific method to be accessed by anonymous users.

Comment: I configured via Attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AllowAnonymous`  attribute, it means that authorization is not required

```
[AllowAnonymous]
  public ActionResult GetLogs() {
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: Does this decoration mandate any other decorator to be present/absent?

Comment: It does not requires anything to be present only this one is enough to allow anonymous users

Comment: @David Tvildiani... How far this approach is secure? Can you please elaborate on this approach from the security standpoint? Ex., As we know, we can make changes in web.config and make a URL accessible for anyone. But this has security vulnerability and this approach is not preferred. Likewise, does your approach has any limitation?

Comment: @PrasathGovind What you wanted was to allow anonymous users, so what security are you talking about ? if you want anonymous users to access that resource, there is no security requirement, right ? (I am not talking about incorrect method implementation where you may have "leakage")

Comment: @Dave... What I am talking about is the 'secure way of allowing anyone' to access the URL. It should not be like I add an attribute and some other URL is also accessible by anyone.

Comment: @PrasathGovind it is attribute, so where you add it ONLY  that controller method is affected.